# Connecting PC ethernet port to WAN port of router

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, nmap, wan

I would like to perform `nmap` scanning on the WAN port of my router from my PC by connecting the ethernet port of the PC directly to the WAN port of the router. How can I assign an IP address to the WAN port of my router from my PC and establish a connection to it? What are the procedures and software I need to have?

I can not do nmap scaning from internet using my public ip, because ISP is blocking all scaning from internet to my router. I do not want to call and ask ISP to disable firewall , since, some hackers may exploit this unprotected window by shear chance.

Comment: For modems I have used, you can either try DCHP or set up a Static IP for the IP the modem has. Also Subnet Mask and Gateway.

Comment: This feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please ask about what it is you're actually trying to achieve, not about how you think you can achieve it. Basically, you're asking "how do I break a window?" when what you want to do is get through the door into the building.

Comment: @John , what subnetmask, gateway do I need to set in router. What ip I need to set in pc ?

Comment: You get these values from your ISP.  Static IP needs a mask (for this, like 255.255.255.255) and a gateway to make a connection

Comment: @John , since I am connecting my PC eathernet directly to WAN of router, I wouldn't be able to use ISP provided gateway , and mask. Would I?

Answer (score 0):

If your router has an Ethernet WAN port and is configured to get its address via DHCP, then you just need to run a DHCP server on your PC once you've connected your PC to the router's WAN port via an Ethernet cable. On Windows and macOS, the easiest way to start up a DHCP server process would be to turn on Internet [Connection] Sharing, which automatically starts up a DHCP server process to serve IP address leases to the downstream/private network.